# Properly dismissing (or "destructing") views in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm concerned about **tiny lags and memory issues, and how they might scale.**

My app is programmed using Swift and I've been doing everything in the app programmatically, including page navigation using `presentViewController` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

*Note: the app's page hierarchy can be several pages deep and each page contains quite a number of images.*

I started experiencing *tiny, occasional, lags* which could appear more often on older phones; I can only test on iPhone 6 right now. I also noticed a *small increase in memory* while navigating through pages. Of course the memory level on the app (as observed in XCode) is not the same as opening the app in fresh state compared to going back to the first page after navigating through tens of pages, I'm expecting the memory level comparison could come at least close.

Now, my question: is there a proper way to "destruct" my page views (including UIKit elements, images, etc.) when such page view is dismissed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "page" you mean a viewController: There is no way to directly destroy objects with ARC (automatic reference counting), as they are deallocated automatically when their strong reference counter is zero. Since you experience unusual memory increase, it might be that you have some strong reference cycles in your code. Make sure to declare properties as `weak` wherever necessary. You should check out the [ARC Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) for detailed explanation. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm still learning Swift and I've never used a `weak` property. That's really one good point to look into. The link to the ARC Guide is a huge help!